# If else condition in mysql query

Tags: mysql

How can I use if and else condition in mysql query. Here is my query.

```
SELECT  CASE WHEN IDParent < 1 THEN 'no' ELSE 'yes' END AS ColumnName FROM tableName;
```

Comment: And what is the problem with your current query?

Comment: Agree with Tim, your case is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this;) Take a look of [mysql-if-function](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-if-function.aspx).

```
SELECT If(IDParent < 1, 'no', 'yes') AS ColumnName FROM tableName;
```